Intermittent process stoppage with Requests library in Django app on Google Compute Engine when using Gemini API
I am developing a web application with Django.
The environment is n2-standard-2(debian) on Google Compute Engine.
I am using the requests library to make a request to use gemini-1.5-flash using the API as shown in the following script:
response = session.post(url, headers=headers, json=data, timeout=20)

Normally, [1] is followed by a DEBUG log for [2], but once in 4 times, the process stops working with [1] (no [2] or later is generated and the process stops working as is).
It works fine in the local environment (windows), but it always occurs in the GCE environment.
Please tell me why does it happen and how to collect it.
[1]DEBUG: urllib3.connectionpool:starting new HTTPS connection (1): generativelanguage.googleapis.com: 443
[2]DEBUG: urllib3.connectionpool:https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com:443 “POST /v1/models/gemini-1.5-flash:generateContent?key= hogehoge HTTP/1.1” 200 None

I tried to force a timeout using signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeout_handler) and signal.alarm(20), but no luck
